# Custom attr() method cannot be given a different name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following perfectly working code (written by someone else).  The problem is that if I simply rename the **attr** method, I get an error.  For example, I rename the method to **attrx** and get this error:

```
TypeError: arg.attrx is not a function
```

Here is the working code:

```
function Action(name) {
  this.attr = function(n) {
      if (n=="name") {
          return "action";
      }
  },
  this.val = function() { 
      return name; 
  };
}

Action.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "&" + this.attr("name") + "=" + this.val();
}
```

When a user triggers an event, the following function is called:

```
function serializeElements() {
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    result += (arg.attr("name") + "=" + arg.val() + "&");
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here is the identical code above but it has the **attr** method renamed to **attrx**:

```
function Action(name) {
  this.attrx = function(n) {
      if (n=="name") {
          return "action";
      }
  },
  this.val = function() { 
      return name; 
  };
}

Action.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "&" + this.attrx("name") + "=" + this.val();
}

function serializeElements() {
  var result = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];
    result += (arg.attrx("name") + "=" + arg.val() + "&");
  }
  return result;
}
```

I cannot figure out the reason that the code does not work (see error at top of message) after I rename the method to **attrx** or anything else for that matter.

Note: The web page does include jQuery, but I don't think that is what causes the problem.

Here is the code used to call **serializeElements**:

```
function addStatesListener() {
    $("#states").on("change", function(e) {
    var form    = $(this.form);
    var url     = form.attr("action");
    var type    = form.attr("method");
    // pass 1) jQuery 'country' and 'state' objects and 2) a query string fragment, e.g.: '&action=change_state'
    var data    = serializeElements($("#countries"), $("#states"), new Action("change_state"));
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",   // The type of data that you're expecting back from the server
        success: function(result) {
            $("#cities").html(result);  // list of all cities, e.g.: <option value="Albany"</option>
        }
    });
});
```

}

Comment: did you make `.attrx` a function?  It's not part of a normal library

Comment: Note `arg = arguments[i]`, `arg` isn't an instance of `Action`. You where using default methods that those items have from jQuery, not the ones you defined. Include the arguments passed in `serializeElements` so we can see what the value of `arguments` is.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, I added the code that you requested I include.  I am reading your comment and trying to understand your point at this time.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, you can see that I am passing a reference to the Action object.

Comment: @Caroline, first two arguments are jquery objects which doesn't have attrx methods, only third parameter you are passing has got the Action methods instance. Looping first two arguments will throw that error

Comment: @dinesh is right, and more, put a try catch to the expression indise the loop in `serializeElements` and you, will see that the last argument will print out. Maybe the first code was wrote so to be compliant to jquery methods.

Comment: @dinesh and Mario, Wow!  Thank you very much for your great observations!

Comment: @Caroline the question makes no sense without some idea of what you're actually trying to achieve with this - there's nothing *to* answer in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper answer to your question is want already catch @dinesh, you are passing 3 arguments to your function, and only the third is an `Action` with the `.attrx` method you changed.

Considering you are working on jquery objects, and if you want to clean your code, you could use `.serialize()` method instead of calling the couple `.attr()` and `.val()`.

`.serialize()` is the jquery method to serialize form objects.

So you can change your code as follow:

```
function Action(name) {
    this.serialize=function() {
        return 'name='+encodeURI(name);
    }
}
```

And then your function `serializeElements`:

```
function serializeElements() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return args.reduce(function(a, b){
       if (a) return a.serialize() + '&' + b.serialize();
       if (b) return b.serialize();
    });
}
```

Then you can call it so:

```
var data = serializeElements($("#countries,#states"), new Action("change_state"));
```

As you see, you could put form elements in a comma separated list on jquery selector.

That's it.

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? Please. Elaborate

Comment: I updated my answer. As the code was to serialize the form element with jquery and add some more custom staff, I suggest a more compliant way to do it. Hope the example explain better the issue and the solution too.

Comment: This is not what answers are for. I suspect the OP gave you the answer because no-one has come in and offered anything else. But the OP has not actually asked a question here. The question is in the form "why does X not work when I change the name of my method to Y". No explanation given on what the method change is for or what the OP is even trying to do. And you are answering: "do this and your code is a bit nicer". Honestly...